# How to get part of a string with delimitters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

This may be the very basic question for all your guys. But, I have already tried for more than 2 hour researching here but didn't find the perfect solution.

I have a string in the format

```
var x = "A:B:C:D:E";
```

and I want to extract only till C, or let's say by using ":" delimitter, how can we extract only certain part of string? I have tried various JS function but didn't work out? Could please someone help here.

Edit: Thanks you guys. Found the solution for my problem. Below is the code that I used from one of the comments.

```
var x = "A:B:C:D:E";
var  output=x.split(':').slice(0,3).join(':');
```

Comment: You want `["A", "B", "C"]` or `"A:B:C"`? And what have you tried to achieve it?

Comment: How are you going to know which part to extract? What is the rule of getting this "certain part"? Why "C", not "D" or "B"?

Comment: If you want `["A", "B", "C"]` you can use `split(':', 3);` where second argument is limit upto which splits are returned.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zu2vxj0y/1/

Comment: @void I have used the split function. Below is the code I tried

var x = "A:B:C:D:E";
var y = x.split(':')[2];

and I want "A:B:C" as output

Answer (score 1):

use `substr()` with `.indexOf()`:

```js
var x = "A:B:C:D:E";
var newX = x.substr(0, x.indexOf('C')+1);

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = newX;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: @Jai Your code will only work for the above mentioned string. Above mentioned string was a generic one.
What if my string changes to "ABC:DEF:MENS:HKJH:HJKJ"

Comment: @deepakkumar what is the expected result then?

Comment: @DeepakKumar and what about your so called **edit** isn't that working for you? Which is obvious....;)

Comment: @Jai For the second string, the expected outcome string is "ABC:DEF:MENS". And I suppose, you code won't work for that string. I was looking for a dynamic function which can work for any string in that format.

BTW, the edit i made working well for the result i desire. Thanks for you help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a function using `.indexOf` and `.substr` which expects three parameters, first the string itself, second the character till you want to keep the string, and third the delimiter by which you want to split the string.

```
function _till(str, till, delimiter){
   return str.substr(0, str.indexOf(till)+1);
}
```

Do

```
_till("A:B:C:D:E:F", "C", ":")
```

Will output:

```
A:B:C
```

Comment: Or `split(':', 3)` where second argument is limit upto which splits are required.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia that's cool, didn't knew about this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like

```
var x = "A:B:C:D:E";
var c=  x.split(":").splice(0,3).join("");
console.log(c);
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please check the edit i made in the post. To get the desired output we need to add ":" within the Join function. The desired output was "A:B:C"